# stringstream from double to char, no failed, no exception

Tags: c++, exception, stringstream

my code is just for test. 
I try to check whether stringstream will throw out exceptions when type convert is impossible.

Following is my code. You can check it in your environment.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stringstream stream("432.23");
    char c = 0;
    try {
      if(!stream>>c) {
        cout<<"Error happend"<<endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }
    catch(...) {
      cout<<"Exception happend"<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"c="<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 
c=^@

Shouldn't it find the error?

Answer (score 3):

Operator! has higher priority, than operator>>, so you must change you code to `if(!(stream>>c))`. After that you get c = 4

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has to do with operator precedence

The line

```
if(!stream>>c) {
```

equates to

```
if(0 >> c)
```

To get the expected behavior you need to use parenthesis:

```
if(!(stream>>c)) {
```

Then you will first try to shift and than check the state of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two problems with the code:

`if (!stream>>c` will not test the streams failbit after reading into c, it
will right shift the failbit c (0) steps, since ! has precedence over >>, you
should change it to `if (!(stream>>c))`.

Also reading the char '4' into c will work fine, so it won't be an error even
if you change the if statement.

What you can do if you want a stream to throw exceptions is to set exceptions on the
stream (but it still won't give an error when reading the char '4' into c).

```
stream.exceptions(ios_base::failbit | ios_base::badbit);
```